# Does a desktop application need CAPTCHA?

Tags: network-programming, desktop-application, captcha

I'm coding a **desktop application** for our university . Users need to *signup* before using this software and registration request is sent to a server written by me, too.  So I'm struggling with kind of network application. ( Suppose that the request format is as simple as a HTTP request sent to an arbitrary port number )
But now I'm wondering whether it's necessary to protect registration process using **CAPTCHA** or not?  Do I need to ensure that the signup request is not generated by a computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your application is for a limited user group (your university only), I think you do **not** need a captcha, because the risk is very low that someone is in this group how wants to annoy you.

Also scripting for a desktop application is (a bit) more complicated than for web applications, this will decrease the risk, too. IF you are struggling with bot-registrations you could still ship the captcha as an update and only accept registrations from the updated version, don't you?

Answer (score 1):

I think that would irritate the human users, who, I believe, would make all your users. Please note that on the net, only a small portion of users are bots. What about a campus? How many computers are on a campus to be worry about? Besides, all those computers are supervised by people you know, and even if a program is installed on one of them (or even all of them) to joke with you, you can call the authorities of the university. So if I were you, I would put my time on betterment of other things, instead.

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need CAPTCHA.  CAPTCHA was made because of the limitations imposed by a web browser while still wanting the wide availability that a website provides.  Your application doesn't have either of these limitations.  Your desktop application can implement whatever security methods it wants and it only needs to be distributed to a specific set of clients.

That doesn't mean you shouldn't have some security policies set up to prevent anyone on the school campus (or internet) from telneting to the port and creating an account.  This can most easily be done by using PKI and distributing a unique private key and open public key with the desktop application.  The server can then verify that the client has the private key before accepting registrations (plus you could encrypt any communications between the client/server).  Of course anyone with access to the desktop application could get the private key, but it's at least more secure than not doing anything at all to prove they can register accounts.